# Subtract 2 Datetimes and get a Datetime back

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm trying to subtract 2 datetimes values and get a datetime back in SQL. I currently just do this:

```
DECLARE @difference DATETIME = @endtime - @starttime
```

However, what this does is: when

```
@endTime = '2014-2-22 00:12:00' and @startTime = '2014-2-22 00:00:00'
```

I expected @difference to be 0000-00-00 00:12:00
But instead it is: 1900-01-01 00:12:00

How can I get this fixed? I tried to use DATEDIFF but that returns a specific integer that can be the year, month etc but not a DATETIME.

Comment: 0000-00-00 00:12:00 is not a valid date time in Sql Server. What sort of difference are you trying to find. Can you find the difference in hours or mins and convert to days as necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epoch (zero point) of the SQL Server `datetime` calendar is `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000`. If you do something like

```
select convert(datetime,'')
```

That is the value you will get.

SQL Server's `datetime` data type is composed of 2 signed 32-bit integers. The first is the offset in days from the epoch; the second is the time-of-day expressed as an offset in milliseconds from start-of-day.

When you subtract two datetime values, say `@end` and `@start` it does what you'd expect it to.

- if `@end.time-of-day` is < `@start.time-of-day`, carry a day's worth of milliseconds from `@end.date` and decrement `@end.date`.
- compute the new time-of-day value by subtracting `@start.time-of-day` from `@end.time-of-day`.
- compute the new date by subtracting `@start.date` from @end.date`

If the resulting value is outside the domain of `datetime` (`1753-01-01T00:00:00.000` through `9999-12-31T23:59:59.997`) an error is raised.

You are getting the expected result...**for SQL Server**.

Edited to show the what's going on under the covers:

```
declare @x datetime = '2014-02-22 00:12:00'
declare @y datetime = '2014-02-22 00:00:00'
declare @z datetime = @x - @y

      select 'end' ,
             date        = @x ,
             description = 'days_since_epoch' ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@x) , 1 , 4 ) ) ,
             description = 'time_as_ms_offset' ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@x) , 5 , 4 ) )
union select 'start' ,
             date        = @y ,
             description = 'days_since_epoch'  ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@y) , 1 , 4 ) ) ,
             description = 'time_as_ms_offset' ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@y) , 5 , 4 ) )
union select 'delta' ,
             date        = @z ,
             description = 'days_since_epoch'  ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@z) , 1 , 4 ) ) ,
             description = 'time_as_ms_offset' ,
             value       = convert(int,substring( convert(varbinary(8),@z) , 5 , 4 ) )
```

produces this result, showing the math:

```
      date                    description      value description       value
----- ----------------------- ---------------- ----- ----------------- ------
end   2014-02-22 00:12:00.000 days_since_epoch 41690 time_as_ms_offset 216000
start 2014-02-22 00:00:00.000 days_since_epoch 41690 time_as_ms_offset      0
delta 1900-01-01 00:12:00.000 days_since_epoch     0 time_as_ms_offset 216000
```